# backup original in scp

Tags: shell-script, scp

I have a remote host with a file I want to override with scp.
this is a simple

```
scp 'myfile.ext' 'foo@example.com:/bar/baz'
```

I would like to also "rename" the original "/bar/baz/myfile.xt" into a file, and not override it with the new version. A simple "/bar/baz/myfile.xt~" is enough, but the best would be a counter or the current date.

is there some way to do it with scp?

I would like to minimize the "scp" calls, because I need to always put an interactive password (no, I can't change the authentication method)

Comment: Use `rsync --backup ...`

Comment: there is also `mirrordir`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to rename the original `/bar/baz/myfile.xt` as `/bar/baz/myfile.xt~` or better still, with a counter or date suffix.

You cannot do this directly with `scp`, but here are a couple of alternatives to your original command.

1. Using `rsync`

   ```
   rsync -ab myfile.ext foo@example.com:/bar/baz
   ```

   The `-b` flag tells `rsync` to make a backup if there is a change to the target file. The default is to append `~` but you can change that default. For example this will use today's date (as defined on the source machine):

   ```
   rsync -ab --suffix ".$(date +'%Y%m%d')" myfile.ext foo@example.com:/bar/baz
   ```
2. Using `ssh` with `scp`. I've assumed that `baz` is the name of the target file rather than a directory in which the source file is to be copied:

   ```
   ssh foo@example.com 'cp -p /bar/baz /bar/baz."$(date +'%Y%m%d')"' &&
   scp -p myfile.ext foo@example.com:/bar/baz
   ```

   You could use `mv` instead of `cp` if you preferred, but this would lose any non-standard permissions and hard file links on the true target file.

The `rsync` option is cleaner, but it's not always installed.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be `scp`? I don't think it can rename files for you (apart from copying remote-to-remote, but I never was sure how well that works.)

`sftp` would make it rather straightforward

```
$ echo -e 'rename test test.old\nput test' | sftp user@hostname
```

And you could do it with `ssh`, too, though note that this doesn't copy anything but the data of `test` (no permissions, timestamps...)

```
$ cat test | ssh user@hostname 'mv test "test.$(date +%F_%T)"; cat > test'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mirrordir`

```
Mirror ~/scripts to ~/scripts.backup:
$ mkdir ~/scripts.backup
$ mirrordir -v ~/scripts ~/scripts.backup

If you rerun mirrordir again, only the updated files are copied.

You can mirroring FTP sites:
$ mirrordir -v ftp://ftp.nixcraft.in/pub /home/backup/nixcraft.in/ftp/pub

mirrordir offers tons of option, refer mirrordir man page for more examples and options:
$ man mirrordir
```